# Packaging Libraries with ML models in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, module, libraries, python-packaging

I have a saved model for Sentiment Analysis and code and data along with it. I am trying to create a library that will have functionalities from this code and uses this trained model. I do not get how will I incorporate the model and functionalities dependent upon it.

Can anyone guide me on how to do that specifically?

Edit: Using pickle is the method I went with (answered below)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to know about three things if you want to maintain such a library properly:

- how to build a package
- how to version a package
- how to distribute a package

There is a few ways how you could do that, the most user-friendly at the moment is probably [`poetry`](https://python-poetry.org/), so I'll use that as an example. It [needs to be installed](https://python-poetry.org/docs/#installation) if you want to use this post as a tutorial.

---

In order to have some very basic project skeleton to work with, I'll just assume that you have something similar to this:

```
modelpersister
├───modelpersister
│   ├───model.pkl
│   ├───__init__.py
│   ├───model_definition.py
│   ├───train.py
│   └───analyze.py
└───pyproject.toml
```

- `model.pkl`: the model artifact that you're going to ship with your package
- `__init__.py`: empty, [needs to be there to make this folder a python module](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages)
- `model_definition.py`: contains the class definition and features that define your model
- `train.py`: accepts data to train you model and overwrite the current `model.pkl` file with the result, something roughly like this:

```py
import pickle
from pathlib import Path

from modelpersister.model_definition import SentimentAnalyzer

# overwrite the current model given some new data
def train(data):
    model = SentimentAnalyzer.train(data)

    with open(Path(__file__).parent / "model.pkl") as model_file:
        pickle.dump(model, model_file)
```

- `analyze.py`: accepts data points to analyze them given the current `model.pkl`, something roughly like this:

```py
import pickle
import importlib.resources

from modelpersister.model_definition import MyModel

# load the current model as a package resource (small but important detail)
with importlib.resources.path("modelpersister", "model.pkl") as model_file:
    model: MyModel = pickle.load(model_file)

# make meaningful analyzes available in this file
def estimate(data_point):
    return model.estimate(data_point)
```

- `pyproject.toml`: a metadata file that poetry needs in order to package this code, something very similar to this:

```
[tool.poetry]
name = "modelpersister"
version = "0.1.0"
description = "Ship a sentiment analysis model."
authors = ["Mishaal <my@mail.com>"]
license = "MIT"  # a good default as far as licenses go

[tool.poetry.dependencies]
python = "^3.8"
sklearn = "^0.23"  # or whichever ML library you used for your model definition

[tool.poetry.dev-dependencies]

[build-system]
requires = ["poetry>=0.12"]
build-backend = "poetry.masonry.api"
```

---

Given all of these files being filled with meaningful code and hopefully using a better name than `modelpersister` for the project, your workflow would look roughly like this:

- update your features in `model_definition.py`, train your model with `train.py` on better data, or add new functions in `analysis.py` until you feel like your model is now noticeably better than before
- run `poetry version minor` to update the package version
- run `poetry build` to build your code and model into a source distribution and wheel file that you can, if you want, perform some final tests on
- run `poetry publish` to distribute your package - by default to the [global Python package index](https://pypi.org/), but you can also set up a private PyPI instance [and tell `poetry` about it](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#using-a-private-repository), or upload it manually somewhere else

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I have followed this and succeed into making a library. However, I want to test it before distributing. How can I do that with .tar and .whl? Would it be some command like pip install packagename or do I need to distribute first?

Comment: You're welcome =) Yeah, you'd install them with something like `pip install modelpersisterf-0.1.0-py3-none-any.whl`. A good test to see whether your .whl and .tar are good could be to create fresh virtual environments and installing it into it with the above pip command.